# ¿Hay algún comando o forma de saber si tengo dependencias sin usar en mi proyecto react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vscode, npm, yarn

Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de saber que dependencias no estas utilizando en mi proyecto react.

Answer (score 2):

`depcheck` es una herramienta que analiza dependencias usando la información provista por npm dentro del archivo package.json en tu app de React. Ayuda a identificar qué paquetes están siendo  utilizados en tu aplicación y cuáles no.

En un proyecto React, puedes instalar `depcheck` con el siguiente comando:

```
npm install -g depcheck
```

Posteriormente, utiliza este comando para checkear qué dependencias tienes:

```
depcheck
```

Y esta sería la salida del comando `depcheck`, donde muestra las dependencias que no has usado (*Unused dependencies*) y las que faltan (*Missing dependencies*):

```
Unused dependencies
* @testing-library/user-event
Missing dependencies
* eslint-config-react-app: .\package.json
* babel-eslint: .\package.json
* eslint-plugin-import: .\package.json
* eslint-plugin-flowtype: .\package.json
* eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y: .\package.json
* eslint-plugin-react: .\package.json
* eslint-plugin-react-hooks: .\package.json
```

Asegúrate de que tu carpeta contiene el archivo **package.json**, sino `depcheck` no será capaz de encontrar tus dependencias. Normalmente tendrás que ejecutar este comando en el directorio raíz de tu proyecto.

La otra alternativa a `depcheck` es `npm-check`:

Instalación:

```
npm install -g npm-check
```

Verificación de dependencias:

```
npm-check
```

Salida del comando (marcará las no usadas como *NOTUSED*):

```
...
react-bootstrap NOTUSED?  Still, using react-bootstrap?
                Depcheck did not find code similar to                                                   require('react-bootstrap') or import from                                               'react-bootstrap'.

                Check your code before removing as depcheck                                             isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies                                             can be used.
                Use --skip-unused to skip this check.
                To remove this package: npm uninstall --save react-bootstrap
....
```

Si quieres más información, puedes encontrarla [aquí](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-in-react).